# Buffer Overflow When Declaring Char Array

Tags: visual-c++, dll, com

I've never done any C++/COM work before, so I'm trying to hijack an existing solution and just alter it to my needs.  The project was written and successfully compiled with VC 6 and I'm attempting to work with it now in 2010.  I had to change a few references to get it to compile, but for some reason, the dll I generate is causing an exception on my system (the original works fine).  Doing some research on the error, it looks like I'm getting a buffer overflow when I try to declare a char array.

```
bool CFile::simpleWrite(char* cData)
{
    try{

        // temp result variable
        BOOL bResult = 0;

        // file handle
        HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

        // get the CMain singleton
        CMain* m_pMain = CMain::GetInstance();

        // this point gets synchronization to ensure we get unique file name...
        char cDirFilename[MAX_PATH + 1];
        GetLogFileName(cDirFilename, MAX_PATH);

        // sanity check
        if(strcmp(cDirFilename, "c:\\") == 0)   assert(0);

        // try and create a file
        hFile = CreateFile( cDirFilename, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );

        // if have a good file handle
        if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){

            size_t lenFileData = strlen(cData) + 72;
            char* cFileData = new char[lenFileData];
            _snprintf(cFileData, lenFileData, "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<RootElement>\r\n%s</RootElement>\r\n\0", cData);
...
```

Here is the declaration/assignment for cData (cXML in the calling method).

```
char cXML[EVENT_LOG_MAX_MESSAGE];
// get the CMain singleton
CMain* pMain = CMain::GetInstance();

long lThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();

// put the parameters into XML format
pMain->BuildXML(cXML, EVENT_LOG_MAX_MESSAGE,errLogLevel,userActivityID,methodName,lineNumber,className,AppID,errorDescription,errorID,lThreadID);

// write the data to file
if(!simpleWrite(cXML))
...
```

BuildXML is doing a _snprintf into cXML and returning it.

Here is the stacktrace going from my call into some of the VC files.

```
Test.dll!_heap_alloc_base(unsigned int size)  Line 55   C
Test.dll!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl(unsigned int nSize, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp)  Line 431 + 0x9 bytes C++
Test.dll!_nh_malloc_dbg_impl(unsigned int nSize, int nhFlag, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp)  Line 239 + 0x19 bytes C++
Test.dll!_nh_malloc_dbg(unsigned int nSize, int nhFlag, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine)  Line 302 + 0x1d bytes   C++
Test.dll!malloc(unsigned int nSize)  Line 56 + 0x15 bytes   C++
Test.dll!operator new(unsigned int size)  Line 59 + 0x9 bytes   C++
Test.dll!operator new[](unsigned int count)  Line 6 + 0x9 bytes C++
Test.dll!CFile::simpleWrite(char * cData)  Line 87 + 0xc bytes  C++
```

I'm sure there is some stupid basic mistake, but I can't seem to get it figured out.

Comment: Could you provide more information on `cData` ?

Comment: 72 is an English number.  Programmers use 256.  The code snippet is of course completely meaningless.

Comment: I added some more details about cData, but just wanted to remind that this project compiles and runs fine when its built in VS 6.  This code has been in use for several years and hasn't been modified since 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is most likely somewhere else where you end up corrupting the heap. I notice you use strlen here without adding one for the terminating zero. Have a look in your code to see if you use strlen for allocating memory and copying somewhere, because I think you're corrupting the heap by allocating one byte too little and then strcpy'ing to it.

Comment: Had a thought; have a look at where you allocate cData and copy to it. Are you by any chance doing cData=new char[strlen(oldString)]; strcpy(cData,oldString) ?
That would lead to heap corruption as the terminating 0 overwrites the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, this was all my own stupidity.  This COM application had a dependency that I wasn't aware of.  Never saw anything trying to look for it in the process monitor and the project had a local copy of the file for compile purposes apparently.  Thanks for the input though.